# Python: Turning arrays into text files

Tags: python, text-files

I have this processed data in the format of:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and so on. How could I take this list and turn it into a .txt file?

Comment: What do you want the final text file to look like? One number per line? Or a comma-separated list of numbers (or words, etc.)?

Comment: Do you want to later recover the data back into a Python list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can write to a file using the [write](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) command. `write()` writes the contents of a string into the buffer. Don't forget to close the file as well using the `close()` function.

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

out = open("output.txt", "w")

for i in data:
    out.write(str(i) + "\n")

out.close()
```

Comment: Don't need to flush before closing. Prefer `with` in new code for file operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(r'C:\txtfile\exported_array.txt', 'w+') as txt_export:
    for i in x: txt_export.writelines(str(i))
```

will save `123456` into txt

```
with open(r'C:\txtfile\exported_array.txt', 'w+') as txt_export:
    for i in x: txt_export.writelines(str(i)+',')
```

will save `1,2,3,4,5,6,` into txt

```
with open(r'C:\txtfile\exported_array.txt', 'w+') as txt_export:
    for i in x: txt_export.writelines(str(i)+'\n')
```

will save

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

into txt

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7, to produce one number per line:

```
with open('list.txt', 'w') as f:
    print >> f, '\n'.join(str(xi) for xi in x)
```

You can use any other join string, like `','` to produce the numbers comma-separated all on one line.